# android fragment call from custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, call, customdialog

i am calling fragment from custom dialog. but i cant call fragment. 
my onClick calling function

```
  public void text_noteClick(View v){
    Fragment fragments = new Text_Note_Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.layout.note_text, fragments);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Toast is works successfully. 
Text_Note_Fragment class is

```
public class Text_Note_Fragment extends Fragment {
public Text_Note_Fragment() {

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_text,container,false);
    return view;
}
```

}
i think problem is Fragment replacing function. 
sorry for my English :) TNX

Comment: Your text_noteClick() method is in activity or in fragment?

Comment: in the MainActivity->protected Dialog OnCreateDialgo(){ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this line is the root cause.

```
transaction.replace(R.layout.note_text, fragments);
```

I see you use `R.layout.note_text` in `onCreateView` function, that's the layout xml for your fragment. but why you use it in replace function? you should use a container(often a FrameLayout), like this.

```
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragments);
```

Comment: thanks @zdd. i tried to Fragment fragment = new Text_note_fragment(); but its dont works

Comment: i am using `        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.layout.checklist_note,fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();` but no view found for checklist_note ... i dont understand it

Comment: You need to define a framelayout with id "container" in your xml layout file and use the `replace` function.

Comment: Why must FrameLayout?

Comment: often framelayout, since it is a container. you can use other layout as well.